# Time.now not changing in partial - rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I am rendering a partial on click event

```
$('#btnAddItem').on('click', function(){
  $('.item_list').append("<%= escape_javascript(render partial:'item_fields.html.erb') %>")
})
```

In partial I am trying to print Time.now but I am getting same time, whenever I click the button - '#btnAddItem'

Partial code:

```
<%= Time.now %>
```

Why I am getting same time? How can I get different time each-time I click?

**Update:** Need to store time.now in ruby variable, which will be used further.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that jquery can't update ruby variables ... you will need to hit the server for that.

Answer (score 1):

The following erb,

```
<%= Time.now %>
```

is evaluated server side when rendering the views.

The javascript is run client side with the already rendered views, thus the time will not change. If you want to replace the time using Javascript you will need to wrap it in a div and replace it's content with the current time.

Comment: I need to store Time.now in ruby variable

Comment: Then change your question ... as it stands ... it's really not clear what you want. Your question mentions nothing of a variable ... I assume in your partial? Post that if so.

Comment: Updated the question

Answer (score 0):

If you need to change some value on the back-end, you'll need to call it. Try to create a controller action for that and request it by an ajax call.

```
$('#btnAddItem').on('click', function(){
  $.get('<%= new_item_path %>').done(function(data){
    $('.item_list').append(data)
  })
})
```